# Generic reading of delimited protobuf message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am writing a server that is going to receive delimited protobuf messages that were written by Message.writeDelimitedTo(OutputStream).

The server doesn't know or care about the actual message contents therefore I am not interested in deserializing it. I am only interested in getting the message size (and then the respective bytes).

Is there a function that can handle reading that information without knowing the type? If not is there some kind of inputStream.readVarInt32() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a [`CodedInputStream`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream) you could then just call `readBytes()` or `readByteArray()` until `isAtEnd()` returns true... basically treating a message as if it were a `bytes` field (it's just a length-delimited field on the wire).